# Insert custom widget in newsletter

Tags: newsletter, widget

I'm trying to create a simple custom widget to insert into a newsletter template which just gets x amount of products from a category and displays them.

Not really too sure how I do this so just starting off by trying to get the widget recognised in the newsletter template widget drop down list.

I've just copied the Catalog/Product/New.php and Catalog/Product/Widget/New.php blocks into my module and renamed them Range.php.

This is what I have so far, but can't get it to display in the newsletter template widget drop down list after you click 'insert widget'. Any ideas?

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mode_Newsletter>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mode_Newsletter>
    </modules>
    <blocks>
        <newsletter>
            <class>Mode_Newsletter_Block</class>
        </newsletter>
    </blocks>
</config>
```

widget.xml:

```
<widgets>
    <range_products type="newsletter/catalog_product_widget_range" translate="name description" module="newsletter">
        <name>Catalog Range Products List</name>
        <description>List of Products that are set as Range</description>
        <is_email_compatible>1</is_email_compatible>
        <parameters>
            <products_count translate="label">
                <required>1</required>
                <visible>1</visible>
                <value>5</value>
                <label>Number of Products to Display</label>
                <type>text</type>
            </products_count>
            <template>
                <required>1</required>
                <visible>1</visible>
                <label>Template</label>
                <type>select</type>
                <value>catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml</value>
                <values>
                    <default translate="label">
                        <value>catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml</value>
                        <label>New Products Grid Template</label>
                    </default>
                    <list translate="label">
                        <value>catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml</value>
                        <label>New Products List Template</label>
                    </list>
                </values>
            </template>
            <cache_lifetime translate="label description">
                <label>Cache Lifetime (Seconds)</label>
                <description>86400 by default, if not set. To refresh instantly, Clear the Blocks HTML Output Cache.</description>
                <visible>1</visible>
                <type>text</type>
            </cache_lifetime>
        </parameters>
    </range_products>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing tag in widget.xml should be `</widgets>` not `</widget>`.